# How to parse text content from epub in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo, epub, epub.js

I am trying to figure out a way to extract the text from .epub files, but I am unsure how to do this.

The closest I can get is with epubjs-react-native where I can at least get the epub files to display on the screen.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Reader, ReaderProvider } from '@epubjs-react-native/core';
import { useFileSystem } from '@epubjs-react-native/expo-file-system';

export default function App() {
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ReaderProvider>
        <Reader
          src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/moby-dick/OPS/package.opf"
          width={width}
          height={height}
          fileSystem={useFileSystem}
        />
      </ReaderProvider>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

But I don't see any way to parse the text. I am open to using another package instead of this one, but this is all I have found so far that isn't outdated.